# WHERE Clause and 30 days after a date

Tags: sql, where-clause, between

I am making a query and in the WHERE clause, I am looking to query on two conditions.

First is I want only records that have a '2' in size.

Second, my main question, I want to find only records that are 30 days after a specified date column (date registered).

I am having trouble querying out 30 days after that date.

Does anyone know where I should start with this?

```
WITH head as (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM user
    JOIN jobs
    ON user.user_id = jobs.user_id
    WHERE size = ‘2’ AND <<<THIS IS WHERE I WANT 30 DAYS AFTER THE DATE>>>
```

Thank you!

Comment: which databse are you using, they all use specific functions

Comment: Your query is using _pretentious-punctuation_ instead of ASCII apostrophes - change `‘2’` to `'2'`.

Comment: _"I want to find only records that are 30 days after a specified date column  (date registered)."_ - we need the names of **both** columns (and which table they belong to), otherwise your question is unanswerable - and we need to know exactly what RDBMS you're using, as (annoyingly) practifcally every DB has its own mutually-incompatible SQL extensions for date predicates.